# How to prevent FCM from converting nested json objects to string in Data Message notifications in react-native

Tags: typescript, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I'm using firebase in my react-native project (with typescript), I set up all thing correctly and it works fine with `data` messages like below:

```
{
  "to": "fcm-token",

  "data": {
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value1",
    "field3": "value1"
  }
}
```

in my App, I can access my data using `data` filed of `RemoteMessage` like below:

```
const data: MyDataType = remoteMessage.data;
const {/* destructed fields */} = data;
```

**But** when my server send nested Object to FCM server, it converts them to string and so I can not access them directly like above.

this is what my server send to FCM server:

```
{
  "to": "fcm-token",

  "data": {
    "field1": {
      "subfield1": "subvalue1",
      "subfield2": "subvalue2",
    },
    "field2": "value1",
    "field3": "value1"
  }
}
```

and this is what I get in my application:

```
{
  "to": "fcm-token",

  "data": {
    "field1": "{"subfield1": "subvalue1","subfield2": "subvalue2"}", <--- the problem is here, it must be a nested object not string
    "field2": "value1",
    "field3": "value1"
  }
}
```

I set `Content-Type` header to `application/json` in my server post requests, so I don't think there is any problem with my headers.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I prevent FCM from converting my nested objects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`react-native-firebase` author here,

We don't internally convert anything to strings on our implementation, these come through to native as strings already, for example on Android this uses the `RemoteMessage` FCM class - where we call `getData()` which as you can see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.html#getData()) returns strings only.

They way I've got around this myself if I want nested data is to have just a single data field where I provide all my data to as a single JSON string, then when receiving it I only need to JSON.parse a single field to get the structure back. E.g.

```js
const data = {
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value1",
  "field3": {
    "subfield1": "subvalue1",
  }
}

const payload = {
  "to": "fcm-token",
  "data": {
    "json": JSON.stringify(data),
  }
}
```

```js
const data: MyDataType = remoteMessage.data;
const { field1, field2, field3 } = JSON.parse(data.json);

console.log(field3.subfield1);
```

Alternatively, you can flatten your data object before sending using something like [this](https://github.com/invertase/deeps#flatten-object-joiner) and then unflatten on the receiving end using something like [this](https://github.com/invertase/deeps#unflatten).

Hope this helps.

Comment: To avoid errors on certain platforms, make sure the values respect their forms. That is, in the `data` object above, if `value1` is an int you should remove the quotes. Same rule for boolean

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the documentation for [message type in the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#Message.FIELDS.data), you'll see that `data` is declared as:

```
"data": {
  string: string,
  ...
},
```

So the `data` field can only hold string values, not more complex objects.

If you want to store more complex values, encode them as a string first and then decode them on the client, for example with `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`.